# Ajax call returning undefined

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have two js files named main.js and utility.js.  I am calling the ajax from main.js and i want the json response in main.js.

Main.js:

```
var details= getUIContent();
```

Utility.js:

```
    function getUIContent(){  
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "http://abc.com/portal",
           async: false,
           success: function(message){              
               channels = message.data.length; 
                   alert('the channel length'+channels);            
               return message;
           } 
         });
}
```

I am getting the response in utility.js. The problem is i am not able to get the response in main.js. It is giving the error like undefined.

Can anyone help me

Comment: welcome to the world of async processing!!! you can't return a value from a async method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said you cannot return value from a async method like `ajax()`.

The solution here is to use a callback method

```
function getUIContent(callback){  
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://abc.com/portal",
        async: false,
        success: function(message){              
            channels = message.data.length; 
            alert('the channel length'+channels);            
            callback(message);
        } 
    });
}

getUIContent(function(details){
    //do whatever you want to do with details here
});
```

Or return a promise from the method

```
function getUIContent(){  
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://abc.com/portal",
        async: false,
        success: function(message){              
            channels = message.data.length; 
            alert('the channel length'+channels);            
        } 
    });
}

getUIContent.done(function(details){
    //do whatever you want to do with details here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems message.data is not returned from the server. 
Please verify your server side code to ensure data is added to your response or not.